# Doc2Vec configuration

Tags: python, similarity, word2vec, gensim, doc2vec

I have about 200-600k documents of user descriptions.

and I'm using `gensim` Doc2Vec model.

I wanted to ask what would be the best fit model configuration so I can do a contextual search on my documents? I want to enter a free text query and get the best similar results for this query. Some of my queries including unique words that are important.

For example: "I need an English speaker for ..."

with my current configuration:

`Doc2Vec(dm=0, size=100, negative=5, hs=0, min_count=2, sample=1e-4,  workers=cores)`

I'm getting really good results but, for my example it will find a description with a speaker inside but not an English one, it can be German speaker.

Is there a better configuration of those examples?

Comment: Are the queries similar to the user-descriptions? Are all words in the queries also in the trained/candidate-document set? Was the choice of `min_count=2` driven by meta-optimization? (Often retaining such infrequent words interferes with the quality of word/text-vectors.) How are you calculating a vector for the query (and to what extent was that optimized)?

Comment: @gojomo the queries are similar to the user-description. I just chose min_count without any reason, I just saw it in one of the blogs. I calculate the vector with infer_vector function